# put one element of a list between all elements of another list

Tags: python, list

I have two list of different lenghts.

```
list_a = ['pineapple', 'banana', 'mango']
list_b = ['tropical']
```

I want to combine them as follows:

```
final_list = ['pineapple', 'tropical', 'banana', 'tropical', 'mango', 'tropical']
```

the goal is to get a dataframe in the end that includes the variable "fruits" and the variable "origin". I will do that by creating a list that displays only every second element and combine then afterwards.

What I already tried:

```
fruit_origin = list_b[0]
desired_list = list(map(fruit_origin.__add__, list_a))
```

but this returns it like this:

```
['pineappletropical', 'bananatropical', 'mangotropical']
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), and a nested [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) à la:

```
from itertools import cycle

list_a = ['pineapple', 'banana', 'mango']
list_b = ['tropical']

[x for tpl in zip(list_a, cycle(list_b)) for x in tpl]
# ['pineapple', 'tropical', 'banana', 'tropical', 'mango', 'tropical']
```

You can also use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the pairs, as suggested by @Matthias:

```
from itertools import cycle, chain

[*chain(*zip(list_a, cycle(list_b)))]  # Python >= 3.5
# or more verbose
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list_a, cycle(list_b))))
```

Comment: I had the same idea but I used `itertools.chain`:  `list(chain(*zip(list_a, cycle(list_b))))`

Comment: Thank you both a lot - both options work!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to map the origin which I'm assuming is only the 1 element in the list. You can try this:

```
desired_list = []
for fruit in list_a:
   desired_list.append(fruit)
   desired_list.append(list_b[0])


print(desired_list)
```

Output:

```
['pineapple', 'tropical', 'banana', 'tropical', 'mango', 'tropical']
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine `itertools.cycle`,  `zip` and `itertools.chain`

```
cycle(['tropical']) 
=> 'tropical', 'tropical', 'tropical', 'tropical', ...

zip(['pineapple', 'banana', 'mango'], ['tropical', 'tropical', 'tropical'])
=> [('pineapple', 'tropical'), ('banana', 'tropical'), ('mango', 'tropical')]

list(chain(*[('pineapple', 'tropical'), ('banana', 'tropical'), ('mango', 'tropical')]))
=> ['pineapple', 'tropical', 'banana', 'tropical', 'mango', 'tropical']
```

Final code

```
result = list(chain(*zip(list_a, cycle(list_b))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply second list by number of items in the first list, and use `zip` and  comprehension like this:

```py
[item for x in zip(list_a, list_b*len(list_a)) for item in x]
Out[7]: ['pineapple', 'tropical', 'banana', 'tropical', 'mango', 'tropical']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a nested loop is more readable in this case than a one liner

```
list_a = ['pineapple', 'banana', 'mango']
list_b = ['tropical']

final_list = []
for a in list_a:
    final_list.append(a)
    for b in list_b:
        final_list.append(b)
```